# Connect sensors to the raspberry pi using the inbuilt wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3, bluetooth

I am able to connect sensors using the GPIO pins.

**My Question is:**

Is there any possible way to connect any kind of sensors to the raspberry pi via Bluetooth or wifi?

And get the data via the same!

Comment: use wifi enabled sensors - OK that's vague, but what type of sensors are you wishing to connect?

Comment: any kind, like temperature, tachometer, motion, etc can you link me any?

Comment: I was kidding about wifi enabled sensors - you have to make them  yourself - e.g. I have a bunch of ESP8266's with temperature, humidity and/or barometric pressure sensors which send data to a Rpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that a 'normal' sensor module would have a wireless interface baked in. That would massively increase its cost while appealing to a relatively small market segment.

The cheapest, easiest method I'm aware of for adding wireless capabilities to sensors is to use an [ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) module, which is basically an Arduino with a WiFi antenna. The entry level modules (ES01) are available for a little over £1/unit from China via Ebay. You would connect sensors to the ESP8266 GPIO pins, relay the data over WiFi, and from there the easiest route to communicating with them would be with something like a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) program run on the Pi.

Comment: Don't get the 01 if you want to connect anything too complex, i.e. SPI or I2C connections - I'd recommend the 12F, 12E or 07 at least

Comment: The larger/slightly more expensive modules will definitely make life easier, but it is possible to run I2C on an ES-01: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-the-ESP8266-01-pins/step2/Best-Trick-Use-I2C/ .

Comment: the additional 9 resistors all but nullify the size difference :p

Comment: No argument there. Still, I think, *cheaper*, but definitely not the easy route.