# want to receive 5 to 6 sensor(connected to arduino) data to raspberry using single devices

Tags: wifi, arduino, xbee

Is that any single devices which can receive different sensor data connected to arduino to raspberry pi? i am thinking to use two NRF24L01 for transmitting and receive data from arduino to raspberry. if any simpler method is there ,then plz suggest

i want to interface 3 soil moisture sensor,3 stepper motor,and 1 dc motor which are all connected to arduino and control wirelessly via raspberry

Comment: This seems quite similar to: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/connect-sensors-to-the-raspberry-pi-using-the-inbuilt-wifi . It would be worth looking into ditching the Arduino components and replacing them with ESP8266 modules.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the distance between the Raspbery Pi and the Arduino... If it is a very short distance (up to 5-10m) you could consider Bluetooth For longer ranges you could consider RF (your NRF24L01), or Wi-Fi. Any of these three will be variable based on the immediate location and the antenna being used. [Here is a link to some range testing of various NRF24L01 module](https://hallard.me/nrf24l01-real-life-range-test/)s.

For very long distances, you might be better having each end connect to a Wi-Fi access point and send the data over the internet.

You might also want to look at the [FIRMATA](https://github.com/firmata/protocol) and [MQTT](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki), each have libraries for most languages (including Arduino and Raspberry Pi), and they simplify the transfer of (sensor) data between the devices.